# vb6 tracking where a function was called from

Tags: vb6

I recently inherited a VB6 project.  It is pretty involved and my issue is that many different functions call this centralized function.  Meaning when I do a find I get a ton of different locations in the project that make this call.  Is there a way to see in debug mode what function called the function I have a break point on?

For example:
funcA calls funcZ
funcB calls funcZ
funcC calls funcZ
it goes on and on...

If I put a break point on funcZ is there anyway in VB6 that I can see what function called funcZ (A,B or C in my example)?

Just wondering...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to see the call stack.

Answer (score 5):

A nice free tool (every VB6 IDE should have it) that amongst its many cool features is one that shows all calling procedures for any sub or function.

http://www.mztools.com/v3/download.aspx

Answer (score 2):

What you seem to be asking about is a stack trace.  Memory fails how easy/hard this is so a quick google search brought up [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367980/stack-trace-in-vb6) question.  Combine that with some output to the immediate window, and you should be good.

**Edit**: Wim's answer is much better.