# Getting the stack trace in VB6

Tags: c++, vb6, stack-trace

Not to [flog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127645/is-it-possible-to-retrieve-the-call-stack-programmatically-in-vb6) a [dead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367980/stack-trace-in-vb6) [horse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098863/runtime-error-stacktrace-or-location-in-vb6), but I found a project on CodePlex called [StackWalker](http://stackwalker.codeplex.com/), which provides stack trace for native applications (C++ apps).  Not knowing much about modern C++, would this also work for VB6 apps? Are VB6 functions somehow different from those in C++?

Answer (score 6):

That depends first of all on how you build your vb6 app.  Project + Properties, Compile tab.  Ensure that the "Compile to Native Code" radiobutton is selected.  And turn on the "Create Symbolic Debug Info" option is checked, this tool requires a PDB to give useful stack traces.  Beware that it won't work well when you run code from the IDE, that always gets built to p-code.

The harder problem is debugging info for msvbvm60.dll, the VB6 virtual machine.  Most any code you run goes through this support DLL, even when you build to native code.  The PDB you need for it is no longer available from the Microsoft symbol server.  Not sure why, possibly because it really is a dead horse.

Comment: You can get the 6.0.98.2 MSVBVM60.DLL (the one that shipped with XP SP3) MSVBVM60.PDB from the Windows XP SP3 Symbol pack cabinet file (about 250MB).