# Module level error handler

Tags: vb6

Is it possible to have a module level error handler rather than procedure level?

Comment: Not directly. You'll need a procedure level stub that calls a module level handler which can forward to a global (project-wide) error handler.

Comment: Hmm, no. Modules do not retain state. There's no way for a module to know that it's supposed to handle errors. Can you give more information about the specific problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

- Use the free add-in [MZ Tools](http://www.mztools.com/index.aspx) to put an error handler in each routine automatically.
- And see [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127645/is-it-possible-to-retrieve-the-call-stack-programmatically-in-vb6) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116289/what-is-the-better-way-to-handle-errors-in-vb6) for best practises in VB6 error handlers.