# How to pass error back to calling function?

Tags: vb6, error-handling

What is the best way in VB6 to pass an error back to the calling function?

```
1    On Error Resume Next
2    ' do something
3    If Err.Number <> 3026 Or Err <> 0 Then ?????????
```

How would you send the error in Line 3 back to the calling function?  Is the following the only way to achieve this?

```
errNum = Err.Number
On Error Goto 0    
Err.Raise errNum
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `On Error GoTo` and re-raise the error in the handler with `Err.Raise`.

```
Private Function DoSomething(ByVal Arg as String)

    On Error GoTo Handler

    Dim ThisVar as String
    Dim ThatVar as Long

    ' Code here to implement DoSomething...

    Exit Function

Handler:
    Err.Raise Err.Number, , "MiscFunctions.DoSomething: " & Err.Description

End Function
```

You'll then be able to get the error number and description in the caller via `Err.Number` and `Err.Description`.

If the caller is also using `On Error GoTo`, you'll see them in the handler there.

If the caller is using `On Error Resume Next`, then you can still use those same variables inline.

I prefer the first option, using On Error Goto in all functions and subs, because it seems like the natural way to use VB6's built-in error raising features. You can also update the description in the called function's handler, like the example above, and get a pseudo call stack you can eventually log or display to yourself during debugging.

More VB6 error handling thoughts here:

[Is it possible to retrieve the call stack programmatically in VB6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127645)

[How to clean up error handling in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258711)

Answer (score 0):

Why not add `ByRef errorCode as Long` to the called function's args and set it equal to Err.Number after `' do something`

Or you could have a public field called `ErrorCode as Long` that you could set after `' do something`

I have worked with a lot of industrial control APIs and both of these methods have been used.

Comment: How in that case would the calling function's error handler be triggered?

Comment: I guess I misunderstood. Try `On Error Goto 0` after `' do something` to restore the error handling of the calling function. You ignored it with `On Error Resume Next`

Comment: Yes but how do I re-raise the error so the calling function handles the error?  The error has already been handled by `On Error Resume Next`, so it would need to be raised again.

Comment: Try this: replace `On Error Resume Next` with `On Error Goto ErrHandler`
Have an error handler that stores the `Err.Number`, `Err.source`, `Err.Description` information, then does a `Resume`.
When you are ready to exit the method, do an `Err.Raise` using the information stored before as arguments.

Sorry I don't have VB6 installed anymore. I hope that works.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily send the error to the upper (calling) sub/function as long as the function that raises the error does not have (ON ERROR RESUME ---), that way, error handling is left in the upper level only. Otherwise you will have to handle the error inside the called function

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
     Dim test As Integer
     On Error Resume Next
     test = myFunction     'Calling a function that is known to have an error
     If Err <> 0 Then
         MsgBox "MyFunction failed because:" & Err.Description 'Error is passed
     End If

End Sub

'--------------------------    

Function myFunction() As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1
    i = 4 / 0   'This will raise an Error, and control returns to the calling sub
    i = 2       'This will never get executed
    myFunction = i
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to pass the error back to the original caller without handling it, then you want to remove any ON ERROR in the child function:

```
Public Sub ParentSub()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    ' do something
    Call ChildSub()
    ' do something
    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    ' handle the error here
End Sub

Public Sub ChildSub()
    ' do something
    ' if there is an error here, the error will be handled in ErrorHandler of ParentSub
End Sub
```

or if you want to handle it in both subs:

```
Public Sub ParentSub()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    ' do something
    Call ChildSub()
    ' do something
    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    ' handle the error here
End Sub

Public Sub ChildSub()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    ' do something
   Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    ' handle the error here and pass it back to the ParentSub to handle it as well
    Err.Raise Err.Number
End Sub
```