# Err.Raise() is ignoring custom description and source

Tags: vba, error-handling

I have a class module with a Let function that raises a custom error an example is shown below

```
Private pValue As Double
Public Property Let Value(v As Double)
    If v < 0 Then
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 1, "error source", "error description"
    Else
        pValue = v
    End If

End Property
```

In another sub I call the class function on an object (Example) and raise the error by passing a value less than 0. In this same sub I have error handling set up to catch multiple errors based on the error numbers.

```
Sub TestSub()
Dim Example As Test
Set Example = New Test

On Error GoTo errorHandler
Example.Value = -1
On Error GoTo 0

Exit Sub

errorHandler:
MsgBox Err.Number & "," & Err.Description & " in " & Err.Source

End Sub
```

The message box prints out the correct error number but the description is the generic Method ~ of object ~ failed, and the source is the generic VBAProject. I'd really like it to print out the error message I gave to Err.Raise. Does anyone know what the issue is here? I have error handling set to break on unhandled errors.

The message displayed in the message box is:

> Method 'Value' of object '_Test' failed

**Edit:** Updated the code to a full scenario where the problem occurs

Comment: unable to replicate with an equivalent set up. Your real code must do something more than the simplified code above does. Can you expand it?

Comment: I replicated the problem with the following code
Class:

    `Private pValue As Double
    Public Property Let Value(v As Double)
        If v < 0 Then
            Err.Raise vbObjectError + 1, "error source", "error description"
        Else
            pValue = v
        End If

    End Property`

Sub:
    
    `Sub TestSub()
    Dim Example As Test
    Set Example = New Test
    On Error GoTo errorHandler
    Example.Value = -1
    On Error GoTo 0

    Exit Sub`

    errorHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description

    End Sub`

Comment: strange then - i pasted your code in and got the "error description" text as intended. I also have break on unhandled errors set. I do not know what could cause a difference in how it runs on different machines. Are you on Windows?

Comment: No, I'm on a mac. That would seem odd if that was the culprit, but certainly could be. I have no way to verify on Windows. If I raise the error in the same Sub as the error handler i.e: 
`Sub TestSub() 
On Error GoTo errorHandler
Err.Raise vbObjectError + 1, "error source", "error description"

Exit Sub
errorHandler:
MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub`

Then the msgBox displays "error description" the problem is coming from raising the error within a class module

Comment: Does the Mac version have an "Error Handling" section in the VBA options dialog?

Comment: @Bond, yes. I have it set to Break on Unhandled Errors. If I switch over to Break in Class Module the error dialog box will appear when an error is raised with the end, and debug buttons. The error description message passed to Err.Raise is displayed in this box. However I was hoping to avoid this form of error handling as it doesn't redirect to the specified error handling section of the code. I was under the assumption that the Err object was passed down the call stack and that it's properties would remain intact when passed from class module to subroutine.

Comment: I have the same issue as you. Really struggling with what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I figured out that the behaviour changed when the instance of the error raising class was typed explicitly. So if you change the type of your class to variant you should keep your custom error message:

```
Sub TestSub()
  Dim Example As Variant   'use Variant instead of Test to keep your custom error message
  Set Example = New Test

  On Error GoTo errorHandler
  Example.Value = -1
  On Error GoTo 0
  Exit Sub

errorHandler:
  MsgBox Err.Number & "," & Err.Description & " in " & Err.Source
End Sub
```