# vba prevent error.raise from stopping code execution

Tags: vba, excel

I have a bunch of vba code that was written using the `.Raise` and `On Error` methods to deal with exceptions. In most cases this works well, but in some functions we want the execution to continue notwithstanding the exception. In such cases, the developers used `On Error GoTo 0`. The issue is that execution continues only after the error message box is dismissed.

Thus my question is: is there a way to suppress all message boxes created by the `.Raise` method for a certain range of code? I've tried `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` but the alerts from `.Raise` are still displayed.

Thanks!

Comment: It would help to show an example of the exact type of code you're dealing with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`On Error GoTo 0` restores the [normal error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12687105/11683). You use it to cancel a previously set `On Error Goto ...`.

What you want is `On Error Resume Next`.