# VBA on open workbook exits code?

Tags: vba, excel

This is the part of the code

```
Dim lx_objectExcel As New Excel.Application
Dim lx_wrkBkSrc As Workbook
Dim lx_wrkShSrc  as WorkSheet

'Using lx_objectExcel.Workbooks.Open WORKS but not Workbooks.Open     
'lx_objectExcel.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=lv_path, ReadOnly:=True) 
Set lx_wrkBkSrc  = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=lv_path, ReadOnly:=True)
```

Using a new instance works

```
lx_objectExcel.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=lv_shrPath, ReadOnly:=True)
```

But Using

```
Workbooks.Open(Filename:=lv_shrPath, ReadOnly:=True)
```

the code exits after it opens the file. While debuggig it doesn't go to the next line either; While searching somone had mentioned use "Thisworkbook.Activate", but the code dosen't even enter the next line.
The file is of the type ".xlsm" 
Also Shift is not pressed while opening. I also set application.enableevents to false to prevent any macro from running.

p.s I have asked the question before, but no suitable answer due to my poor questioning

Comment: Are you running the above code from a module? Also, have you checked what macros/UDF's get triggered in the file you are trying to open? they could be the one causing the problem

Comment: This is a good answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/46096253/5448626

Comment: @Zac; there are only some functions not sub in the other xlsm file; I thought Application.EnableEvents prevents running of macros from other files? Doesn't it?

Comment: I think @Vityata link should answer your query

Comment: Oh well!!! I give up...