# VBA function with "On Error GoTo error" always fall on error

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling, goto

Can we use : `On Error GoTo ...` in a VBA **function** ?

I always use it to manage my eventual error inside my Sub but when I use it inside a function it's like it didn't work as expected and always go through. When I remove it the function work well.

There is a specific way to manage error in function ?

**EDIT**

Here is an exemple of one of my function :

```
Function Row_Nbr_In_Sheet(shtName As String) As Integer
  On Error GoTo ErrorManager
  
  Row_Nbr_In_Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(shtName).UsedRange.Rows.Count

ErrorManager:
  MsgBox("Something weird here")
  End
End Function
```

this function work well without "GoTo" but it trigger the MsgBox when I use it. It's exactly the same for each functions of my code.

Comment: Yes, its the same for subs and functions.

Comment: Error handling should work the same in a Sub or Function.  If you post your code we could help you better.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12687105/11683?

Comment: Yes ```On Error GoTo ...``` can be used, but you shouldn't name your error handler "error". VBA doesn't like ambiguous names. Call it for example "eh" (for error handler), thus ```On Error GoTo eh```, and be sure to add a tag with that name in the same sub/function.

Comment: @Vincent It's not a matter of ambiguous name but a keyword. VBA has no problem with ambiguous names as long as they're fully qualified.

Comment: well, it's weird. I will edit my post with some code in few minutes

Comment: `Error` is a keyword, pick something else. The same goes for `Err`.

Comment: I renamed Error into ErrorManager but the issue is still the same

Comment: You need to add `Exit Function` right above `ErrorManager:`.

Comment: this is very specific to my functions, I use "GoTo" in many Sub without any probleme but each time I use it in a function it fail

Comment: Thanks for your help Brian but I guess "End" is stronger than "Exit" if I just exit the function the program will continue with the error

Comment: @Xodarap No, it won't. It won't reach the `exit function` in the case of an error.

Comment: You don't get it, If I reach an error in my process I want to stop everything because each functions are important to get the good result. If I use "Exit function" the function is avoiding but the process continue, if I use End it stop. (I just test it)

Comment: The purpose of an error handler is to handle an error. If you cannot handle an error, you don't handle it, you let it bubble up to the caller. In which case the caller will see it as an error and will be able to handle it or not. One function should not have authority to stop the entire processing, it should only report the error (by not handling it, or re-throwing it). And then only the topmost procedure will include an error handler that will trap everything, display a message box and exit (for which there would not need to be an `End` either).

Comment: OK I understand, I'm still a begginer so I'm not yet able to make a workflow like that by myself at the moment. Thanks to you I understand better the role of the error handler.