# VBA 'Object required' error but works in new worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column containing a spill range:

```
Cat
Dog
Cow
Pig
Chicken
```

The aim is to put these text values in another column but with 5 empty rows in between each value.

When new values are added into the spill range, the other column is updated continuing the 'every 5 rows' pattern. Likewise when values are removed.

The VBA code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range(Range("G2").SpillParent.Address)) Is Nothing Then
    
    Columns(55).ClearContents
    
    Dim srange As Range

    Set srange = Range("G2").SpillingToRange
    Range("BD2") = Range("G2").SpillingToRange.HasSpill
    Range("BD4") = Range("G2").SpillingToRange.Address
    Range("BD6") = Range("G2").SpillingToRange.count

    Dim count As Long, i As Long, nextrow As Long

    count = Range("G2").SpillingToRange.count + 1
    nextrow = 2

    For i = 2 To count
        Sheet1.Cells(nextrow, 55).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 7).Value
        nextrow = Cells(nextrow, 55).Offset(6, 1).Row
    Next
    
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

End Sub
```

The code returns an `Object required` error when I enter the spill formula again to update the worksheet. When I went to track down the problem in a new worksheet, the code works fine and the `Object required` error does not appear. The spill range calculates its values based on another column.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where does the error happen?

Comment: @GSerg The error does not highlight any areas in the code.

Comment: What [error trapping mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12687105/11683) do you have?

Comment: It seems unusual for you to be referring to a specific worksheet (`codename: =sheet1`) when you are running worksheet code.  I haven't analyzed what you are doing, but is that really your intent?  If not, could it be causing a problem?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I changed the `sheet1` but still received the same error.

Comment: How did you change it?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld The worksheet was not actually called `sheet1` so I changed the name to the actual name of the worksheet.

Comment: Why are you using the worksheet codename at all?  And do you mean to use the `codename` or the `name`?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I tried without worksheet name as well, but with no success. I am relatively sure I used the `name` as in the name I entered when renaming the worksheet, not the `codename`.

Comment: If you are using `Sheet1.Cells(...`, `Sheet1` will be the `codename`, not the `name`