# Run-time error 91 in VBA when populating check-box on User-form from SQL

Tags: sql, vba, userform

I am quite new to VBA and SQL, and I am trying to populate a checkbox on a userform in Word's VBA with the column names of a SQL database.
I have managed to verify the connection and list the elements in a table separately, now I just wanted to have them in the checkbox. The initializaiton has the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To rst.Fields.Count
        Me.cboParameter.AddItem rst.Fields(i).Name
    Next i

End Sub
```

When I try to run the private sub I get the run-time error 91 without any lines being highlighted.
Any tips on what the problem might be?

Comment: My bad, I added the remaining lines before the private sub. I broke line 3, and when I hover the rst.Fields.Count I get the <Object variable or With block variable not set>

Comment: Yep, that's what error 91 means (Object variable or With block variable not set). Glad it helped.

Comment: `without any lines being highlighted` - https://stackoverflow.com/q/12687105/11683

Comment: You never initialize `conn` or `rst`. Naturally you get error 91.

Comment: So I need to define my connection string and string of mySQL code to query the table in each private sub?

Comment: If you insist on storing a shared connection instance in a global variable, then no, but you need to initialize it once, which you are not doing anywhere. What you should do instead is to have a function that returns a connection, and call that from each sub, instead of storing a cached object.

Comment: By copying the initializing connection and querying the database parts before wanting to get fields count and names i get Run Time Error 3265 – Item not found in this collection. If I break the code before Next i I can see it gets the values for the Fields.Count, and even the name of the first item in Fields(i).Name

Comment: Because you are counting to `rst.Fields.Count` and should be counting to `rst.Fields.Count - 1`?

Comment: Ah indeed, I don't know where I lost that from the initial working code. It works! I will try to make it prettier by trying to make a function to reference for the connection. Thanks a lot for your patience, it is quite hard to juggle 2 new programming languages and finding solutions :)