# Excel VBA Why won't error bubble up to calling function with error handler?

Tags: excel, vba

When an error occurs inside a function without an On Error statement, I thought it's supposed to bubble up to the first calling parent function with an On Error statement, but for some reason its not working and I have no idea why.

The following code is a minimum reproducible example. It doesn't do anything except demonstrate the error. There are 3 files in the program:

1. In Workbook_Open() function inside ThisWorkbook file, I have the following code:

   ```
    Public Sub Workbook_Open()

        On Error GoTo wtf
        Stop
        Dim f As New Factory
        Call f.createM_DateWithObject(Now)
        MsgBox "A"
        Exit Sub

    wtf:

        MsgBox "B"

    End Sub
   ```
2. Then I have the first class called Factory, which contains only:

   ```
    Public Sub createM_DateWithObject(ByVal dateObj As Date)

        'intentional error
        Dim x As Integer
        x = "asd"

    End Sub
   ```
3. Then I have my second M_Date class:

   ```
    Option Explicit
    Option Base 0

    'ini the object using a date
    Public Sub iniWithObject(ByVal dateObj As Date)

         'does nothing

    End Sub
   ```

The only On Error statement is inside Workbook_Open(), however when I run the code it stops at x = "asd"

[image]

Why isn't the error bubbling up to Workbook_Open() where I can catch it?

Thanks,
Geoff

Comment: Previously:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12687105/break-in-class-module-vs-break-on-unhandled-errors-vb6-error-trapping-options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VBE for excel includes options for class module error handling. So check your options under Tools | Options. You should not enable the option to *Break in Class Modules*

[image]

Comment: Ah ok great thanks. But if I turn off Break in Class Module, and there's an unhandled error, it doesn't show you where in the class the error occurred. Is there a way to keep that part? Also, is that setting file specific? Would every user need to go into VBA to set that?

Comment: Not that I know of - usually for testing I enable break in class modules, and when I'm satisfied with my class code I turn the option off.