# VB6 Program Causing a Runtime Error 380

Tags: vb6

This was a similar thread, but still no luck. [What causes this error? “Runtime error 380: Invalid property value”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979281/what-causes-this-error-runtime-error-380-invalid-property-value)

This program has been out for years running on XP ~ Win8

A recent installation on a Vista Home Premium laptop is producing this error.

Here is the last code before the error:

```
 On Local Error Resume Next

 fSetup.Show

 If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical

 On Local Error GoTo 0
```

It does not it to the if clause.

In the form load of the target form, it never makes it to the If clause

```
If bTestMode Then MsgBox "Setting me.tag", vbOKOnly
Me.Tag = "FormLoad"
If bTestMode Then MsgBox "Me.Tag Set", vbOKOnly    
If bTestMode Then MsgBox "Setting me.tag", vbOKOnly
Me.Tag = "FormLoad"
If bTestMode Then MsgBox "Me.Tag Set", vbOKOnly
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Looks like your problem is down inside of your form, fSetup. What code does that run when it is loading up? (Form_Load, Form_Activate, et al).

Comment: Does fSetup use adodb? If so, you might be being bitten by the [win7 sp1 ADO guid mess](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2011/10/03/yes-we-made-a-mistake-and-are-finally-going-to-fix-it.aspx)

Comment: It is only happening a a Windows Vista Laptop, Window 7 work perfectly

The second batch of code is what fSetup Executes, never makes it there.

Comment: Do you have anything in the Form_Initialize() method in fSetup? That code executes before Form_Load when you use the .Show method on a form that hasn't been created yet.

Answer (score 0):

Turn out System Locale was set to Korean, causing non-unicode VB6 to have trama