# THROW statement in catch block

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to return error details in calling application using SQL stored procedure output parameter. If I use throw in catch block that time in case if procedure not execute successfully then output parameter will not not set with error details and if I ignore throw then it will work.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER proc [dbo].[pt44]
(
    @a int,
    @b int,
    @Msg varchar(2000) output
)
as
begin
    DECLARE @c int
    begin try
        set @c= (@a+@b)
        print 'C Value :' +@c--cast(@c as varchar(20))  error is here
    end try
    begin catch
        set @Msg='Error No. '+CAST(ERROR_NUMBER() AS VARCHAR(200))+'Error Line. '+CAST(ERROR_LINE() AS VARCHAR(200))+' Error Message.'+ERROR_MESSAGE()  
        --;throw
    end catch
end
```

Please tell me the best way how I can pass error to calling application and also want to use throw in SQL Server catch block.

Comment: The information you are trying to pass back via the output parameter is available by the exception if you pass it back to the application.

Comment: I am using vb 6.0 application at front end so there is no try catch block

Comment: are you looking for RAISERROR? 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

Without structured error handling in VB 6, one can use `On Error` to execute error handling code and capture SQL error details. See [the VB6 documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116289/what-is-the-better-way-to-handle-errors-in-vb6) (no longer maintained) for more information and examples.

```
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

' execute proc here
oCmd.Execute

' happy path code here
GoTo Done

:ErrorHandler
' this will show SQL error
MsgBox Err.Description

:Done
```

This is the boiler plate T-SQL catch block code I normally use:

```
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK;
    THROW;
END;
```

Comment: structured error handling in VB 6 some time not able to handle all errors which will occur in back end while executing stored procedure  so that the reason i need proper solution

Comment: @TusharK, you should be able to get all output, including errors, from any SQL query or proc in VB6. However, the VB code must consume all result returned (e.g. Command.NextRecordset). A common practice is to include `SET NOCOUNT ON;` in scripts and procs to ensure rowcount messages don't interfere with application code that doesn't expect them.